# C read a specific line from a file

Tags: c

I need to read line `x` from `file.txt` and store it in the string `string`

I am stumped and have no idea what to do, this is what I have

```
FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
int x = someLine;

if (file == NULL) {
    printf("Error! \n");
    strcpy(string, "ERROR");
    return;
}


fclose(file);
```

Comment: `fread()`? `fgets()` POSIX `getline()`? `fscanf()`? POSIX `read()`? `readv()`? You *do* have options, you know.

Comment: @EOF That's exactly why I am confused, I don't know what to use

Comment: @yobrobob Roll a dice. (And I'm aware "dice" is plural, but nobody ever says "roll a die" in reality)

Comment: Well, that would depend on your usecase. What's special about the line you're looking for?

Comment: @immibis 'getline()' seems like the easiest

Comment: @EOF I want to copy that line (Without the newline) and check if chars that the user enters are in it.

Comment: *What distinguishes the line from the other lines (if any) in the file*?

Comment: If your lines are fixed format records, you could use fseek to put the file pointer at the correct place in the file, and then use fread to read the line in.

Comment: @EOF the lines are just random words

Comment: @immibis: I say "roll a die" all the time.  Your statement `segfaults`.  Sanitize your inputs ;)

Answer (score 1):

this is an answer a simple google search could answer.  However, since I'm already typing I'll go ahead and answer this.

http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-file-io-using-text-files

you need to read the lines and keep track of how many you have read.

```
char buf[1000];

while (fgets(buf,1000, file) != NULL)
    printf("%s",buf);
```

you'll have to look into how fgets works to change this for your use, but this should easily get you to the solution.

Comment: I guess that the OP imagined there was some 'easy' way of reading indexed lines of text.  We know there is not, now so does OP:)